# Unable to access the object using `this`. `this` points to `window` object

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object

I have this Javascript constructor-

```
function TestEngine() {
    this.id='Foo';
}

TestEngine.prototype.fooBar = function() {
    this.id='bar';
    return true;
}

TestEngine.prototype.start = function() {
    this.fooBar();
}

TestEngine.prototype.startMethod = function() {
    inter = setInterval(this.start, 200);
}

var test = new TestEngine();
test.startMethod();
```

Gives me this error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'fooBar'
```

I tried `console.log` and found out that when I call `this.start` from within `setInterval`, `this` points to the `window` object. Why is this so?

Comment: `setInterval` is `window.setInterval` so `this` refers to `window`

Comment: @kidwon - That's not the reason. See my answer below for the correct reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15587589/783743

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` pointer can point to one of many things depending upon the context:

1. In constructor functions (function calls preceded by `new`) `this` points to the newly created instance of the constructor.
2. When a function is called as a method of an object (e.g. `obj.funct()`) then the `this` pointer inside the function points to the object.
3. You can explicitly set what `this` points to by using `call`, `apply` or `bind`.
4. If none of the above then the `this` pointer points to the global object by default. In browsers this is the `window` object.

In your case you're calling `this.start` inside `setInterval`. Now consider this dummy implementation of `setInterval`:

```
function setInterval(funct, delay) {
    // native code
}
```

It's important to understand that `start` is not being called as `this.start`. It's being called as `funct`. It's like doing something like this:

```
var funct = this.start;
funct();
```

Now both these functions would normally execute the same, but there's one tiny problem - the `this` pointer points to the global object in the second case while it points to the current `this` in the first.

An important distinction to make is that we're talking about the `this` pointer inside `start`. Consider:

```
this.start();           // this inside start points to this
var funct = this.start;
funct();                // this inside funct (start) point to window
```

This is not a bug. This is the way JavaScript works. When you call a function as a method of an object (see my second point above) the `this` pointer inside the function points to that object.

In the second case since `funct` is not being called as a method of an object the fourth rule is applied by default. Hence `this` points to `window`.

You can solve this problem by binding `start` to the current `this` pointer and then passing it to `setInterval` as follows:

```
setInterval(this.start.bind(this), 200);
```

That's it. Hope this explanation helped you understand a little bit more about the awesomeness of JavaScript.

Comment: I had figured out a dozen ways to _just solve_ this problem. But I wanted the **reason** why my code was not working. And you've explained it really well. Thanks a lot. **`this`** is mysterious.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a neat way to do OOP with javascript:

```
//Global Namespace:
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};

//Classes:
MyNamespace.MyObject = function () {

    this.PublicVar = 'public'; //Public variable
    var _privatVar = 'private'; //Private variable

    //Public methods:
    this.PublicMethod = function () {
    }

    //Private methods:
    function PrivateMethod() {
    }

}

//USAGE EXAMPLE:
var myObj = new MyNamespace.MyObject();
myObj.PublicMethod();
```

This way you encapsulate your methods and variables into a namespace/class to make it much easier use and maintain.

**Therefore you could write your code like this:**

```
    var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};

    //Class: TestEngine
    MyNamespace.TestEngine = function () {

        this.ID = null;
        var _inter = null;

        //Public methods:
        this.StartMethod = function (id) {
            this.ID = id;
            _inter = setInterval(Start, 1000);
        }

        //Private methods:
        function Start() {
            FooBar();
            console.log(this.ID);
        }

        function FooBar() {
            this.ID = 'bar';
            return true;
        }

    }

    //USAGE EXAMPLE:
    var testEngine = new MyNamespace.TestEngine();
    testEngine.StartMethod('Foo');
    console.log(testEngine.ID);
```

Initially, the ID is set to 'Foo' 
After 1 second the ID is set to 'bar'

Notice all variables and methods are encapsulated inside the TestEngine class.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function TestEngine() {
    this.id='Foo';
}

TestEngine.prototype.fooBar = function() {
    this.id='bar';
    return true;
}

TestEngine.prototype.start = function() {
    this.fooBar();
}

TestEngine.prototype.startMethod = function() {
    var self = this;
    var inter = setInterval(function() {
       self.start();
    }, 200);
}

var test = new TestEngine();
test.startMethod();
```

`setInterval` calls `start` function with window context. It means when `start` gets executed, `this` inside `start` function points to `window` object. And window object don't have any method called `fooBar` & you get the error.

### Anonymous function approach:

It is a good practice to pass [`anonymous function`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/&ei=TlJIUd_wI46KrgeDiYCQCg&usg=AFQjCNEoMND3ig9KdKF1tQrR7gsp6sSAjQ&bvm=bv.43828540,d.bmk&cad=rja) to `setInterval` and call your function from it. This will be useful if your function makes use of `this`.

What I did is, created a temp variable `self` & assigned `this` to it when it is pointing your TestEngine instance & calling `self.start()` function with it.

Now inside `start` function, `this` will be pointing to your testInstance & everything will work as expected.

### Bind approach:

[`Bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) will make your life easier & also increase readability of your code.

```
TestEngine.prototype.startMethod = function() {
  setInterval(this.start.bind(this), 200);
}
```