# Javascript Passing a method of an object as a function

Tags: javascript, function, methods

Today I found out a rather strange behaviour that happens when you pass the method of an object as a function in Javascript.

```
 setTimeout(myObject.test, 100); // "this" is the global object window
```

The method "test" is correctly invoked, but "this" is not the object "myObject" but instead the global object "window". I can get the expected behaviour when I do something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){myObject.test()}, 100); // "this" is myObject
```

This seems to me rather strange. Can anybody explain, why this is.

Comment: What you are describing can be strange, when you are used to languages like AS3 or Java - but in JS this is the expected behaviour, the default-scope is "window" for any event or timeout-function ect. so you usually always have to go through anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this pseudo-representation how JavaScript will interpret `setTimeout(myObject.test, 100);`

```
function setTimeout(func, millisec) {
    //some code...
    func(); //"this" in func will point to window
    //some code...
}
```

But when you do this - `setTimeout(function(){myObject.test()}, 100);`, `setTimeout` will execute the anonymous function you passed, so `this` the anonymous function will still point to `window`, but that anonymous function calls another function `myObject.test()`, since, function is being called as a method of an object, `this` will point to that object.

You can solve this by using a cool JS function [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
setTimeout(myObject.test.bind(myObject), 100); //now "this" will point to myObject.
```

A better explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15587589/783743) by a [JS Guru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783743/aadit-m-shah)

Answer (score 1):

The run time will execute the function argument (1st argument) for `setTimeout` on `window` object, and you put the `test` method directly as the argument, so you see `this` is bond to window object in your first case.

In your second case, the function executed on `window` object is your anonymous function `function() { myObject.test() }`, however, the `test` method is invoked on `myObject`, that's why you see `this` is bond to `myObject`