# Pass "this" parent context to function using plain js no jquery

Tags: javascript, this

I am writing helper function to loop through all array elements - just for learning js.

here is the code:

```
function arrayLoop(array, func){

    var ar = array.length,
        i=0;

    for ( i = 0; i < ar; i++ ){
        func(i);
    };

};
```

it is working when i use it like:

```
var foo = ['aa','bb','cc'];

arrayLoop(foo, function(i){
    alert(foo[i]);
});
```

but when i try to do it inside object and want to use this context - error occurs:

```
function test(){

   this.foo = ['aa','bb','cc'];
   this.bar = ['ff','gg','hh'];

}

test.prototype.find = function(){

  arrayLoop(this.foo, function(i){

     alert(this.bar[i])     //error- there is no this.bar 

  };  

};
```

How to pass parent this automatically to arrayLoop function ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change arrayLoop to allow a context parameter:

```
function arrayLoop(array, ctx, func){
    ctx = ctx || window;
    var len = array.length, i = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        func.call(ctx, i);
    }
}

test.prototype.find = function(){
  arrayLoop(this.foo, this, function(i) {
     alert(this.bar[i]);     // this will work
  });
}
```

This lets you pass in the desired `this` value for the callback and it will get set for you then when the callback is called and it will work in all browsers (`.bind()` doesn't work in older browsers).

FYI, you also were missing a `)` in your `find()` function and you seem to like a number of extra semi-colons which do no harm, but don't need to be there.

Answer (score 1):

You could capture it in a closure:

```
test.prototype.find = function() {
    var self = this;
    arrayLoop(this.foo, function(i) {
        alert(self.bar[i]);
    });
};
```

or use the [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

```
test.prototype.find = function() {
    arrayLoop(this.foo, function(i) {
        alert(this.bar[i]);
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: I know this solution but is there any other way to use exactly "this" word  inside ?

Comment: @Kriss - see my answer that uses `this`.

Comment: Yes, you could use the `.bind()` function. I have updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method.

```
test.prototype.find = function(){
    arrayLoop(this.foo, method.bind(this));
}

test.prototype.method = function(i){
    alert(this.bar[i]);
};
```

You can find an explanation why your code is not working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498508/unable-to-access-the-object-using-this-this-points-to-window-object)

Answer (score 0):

[Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function to the object:

```
test.prototype.find = function(){

  arrayLoop(this.foo, function(i){

     alert(this.bar[i])     //error- there is no this.bar 

  }.bind(this));  

};
```