# Javascript - update parent object from child callback

Tags: javascript, callback, parent-child

I would like to set a property of a parent object every time a child object runs a callback function.

I have the following code:

```
function Track(id) {
    this.callback = function(args) {
        this.name = args;
    }

    this.child = new objectName(this.callback, property);
    this.name = this.child.name;
}
```

I want `this.name` to be updated every time `this.callback` is called...Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typical scoping issue, `this` will not reference to parent object when the callback is called.

Try this instead:

```
function Track(id) {
    var that = this;
    this.callback = function(args) {
        that.name = args;
    }

    this.child = new objectName(this.callback, property);
    this.name = this.child.name;
}
```

*edit:* see merlin's comment for a good explanation why `this` can be a cause for problems. There might also be other possibilities to solve this, i.e. the usage of `bind()`, but for that you'll have to pass the parent into the objectName contructor as well.

Comment: The explanation is not correct. What `this` points to will depends on how `objectName` calls it.See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498508/unable-to-access-the-object-using-this-this-points-to-window-object)

Comment: `this` is hardly ever a reference to a function.

Comment: perfect thanks all!  Kevin's answer worked perfectly and merlin's pointer to the other question was an enlightening explanation.  all around great answers.